# New line added to the end of text in Rich TextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a rich textbox in my form (WinForm). I use this for updating description column. When I perform a update operation, it introduces a newline/linefeed character to the end.

How to avoid this newline in a easy way.  Does it need to be handled thru code or manage thru a property?

```
public MyDlg(string strXmlFile)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    strInputXmlFile = strXmlFile;

    xmlDoc.Load(@"c:\temp\SBD_Input.xml");
    node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SBD/Description");

    // Set the description into the rich text box.
    richTextBox1.AppendText(node.InnerText);
}

private void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Put the RTB contents back into node & Import.
    node.InnerText = richTextBox1.Text;
    xmlDoc.ImportNode(node, true);

    // Save the Xml document.
    xmlDoc.Save(@"c:\temp\SBD_Input.xml");

    this.Close();
}
```

Input XML file looks herebelow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SBD>
  <Number> 1234567</Number>
  <Description>EDGES MAY BE BROKEN
  All surfaces are varnished
            --------------------
  Color     |  R  |  G  |  B  |
            -------------------- 

  as dflkjaslödfj lasöj flöaskj flaksjd fölkasjd flöaskjdf 
   askjflj asld fjklöaskjdf laskjfl s falsj flöasjkd f flaskjdf a 
  as djflajs dfl

  </Description>
</SBD>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it WPF or WinForm? Please also add your code.

Comment: I have updated the post with my code & screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the update btn code:

```
node.InnerText = richTextBox1.Text.TrimEnd( '\r', '\n' );
```